# Create SelectList from foreign key where equal to (ASP.NET Core 2/C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a SelectList in my Contracts view. Every contract is associated with an employee with the RoleId == "Sales Rep" || "Manager".

How can I do this and have the SelectList show the EmployeeId followed by their Employee.Firstname and Employee.Lastname (Ex: 1001 - Jon Doe).

[image]

If I could get pointed in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Show some efforts. What have you tried to solve the issue? I/we ask, cause well, the official documentation has more than enough samples on how to do it. Did you read it?

Comment: I've been reading documentation for the past 2 days trying to find something similar. So far the best I have come is to list what I want but not in the format (101 - John Doe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few more hours ontop of my 2 day search... For the future soul:

```
 ViewData["EmployeeId"] = new SelectList(_context.Employee.Where(e => e.RoleId.Contains("Sales Rep") || e.RoleId.Contains("Manager"))
            .Select(e => new { Value = e.EmployeeId, Text = e.EmployeeId + " - " + e.Firstname + " " + e.Lastname }),
            "Value", "Text");
```